# Failed upgrade path for Cassandra 2.0.17 -> 3.11.11 -> 4.0.5

Tags: cassandra

I have Cassandra cluster which has been initially installed Cassandra 2.0.17 version. During the time it has been upgraded through minor and major version, at the end it's on 3.11.11 version.

Now I'm trying to upgrade it to 4.0.5 version, but it exits with following error at startup.

```
ERROR [main] 2022-09-01T07:29:46,009 CassandraDaemon.java:911 - Detected unreadable sstables \
  /data/keyspace1/api_user-c21e2aa0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Data.db,
  /data/keyspace1/group_index-c3a2ced0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Statistics.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_auth-c1c53530a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Summary.db,
  /data/system_auth/roles-5bc52802de2535edaeab188eecebb090/la-1-big-CompressionInfo.db,
  /data/system_auth/roles-5bc52802de2535edaeab188eecebb090/la-1-big-Data.db,
  /data/keyspace1/api_user-c21e2aa0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Filter.db,
  /data/keyspace1/ssl_keystore-cfe03340a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-CompressionInfo.db,
  /data/keyspace1/license_v2-cf226180a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Statistics.db,
  /data/keyspace1/inv_settings-c74b3d60a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Filter.db,
  /data/system_auth/roles-5bc52802de2535edaeab188eecebb090/la-1-big-Summary.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_auth-c1c53530a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-2-big-Index.db,
  /data/keyspace1/group_index-c3a2ced0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Data.db,
  /data/keyspace1/api_user-c21e2aa0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-CompressionInfo.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_index-c3715e90a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Summary.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_index-c3715e90a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Filter.db,
  /data/keyspace1/group_index-c3a2ced0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Filter.db,
  /data/keyspace1/dashboard_groups-c7bf0dd0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-CompressionInfo.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_auth-c1c53530a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-2-big-Statistics.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_auth-c1c53530a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Index.db,
  /data/keyspace1/group_index-c3a2ced0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Index.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_index-c3715e90a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Statistics.db,
  /data/keyspace1/api_user-c21e2aa0a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Index.db,
  /data/keyspace1/user_auth-c1c53530a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Statistics.db,
  /data/keyspace1/ssl_keystore-cfe03340a72b11e9ad8a2b34a639a098/la-1-big-Statistics.db
```

Clusters with initial version 3.X.X version I could upgrade 4.0.5 successfully.
Final cassandra.yaml is the same for both cases (2.X.X -->, 3.X.X -->)

Is it supported to upgrade following path Cassandra 2.0.17 -> 3.x.x -> 4.0.5 ?

Comment: To Erick's point, if you haven't run `upgradesstables` yet, you can always go back to 3.11, run `upgradesstables`, and then go back to 4.0.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upgrade path is not the problem. The issue is that you still have SSTables from a very old version of Cassandra.

Files with the prefix of `la-` is the [`BigFormat` for Cassandra 2.2](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L128):

```
        public static final String current_version = "la";
```

The earliest SSTable format that [Cassandra 4.0 can read is `ma`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.5/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L115-L116):

```
        public static final String current_version = "nb";
        public static final String earliest_supported_version = "ma";
```

We always recommend that you run `upgradesstables` on all nodes BEFORE you upgrade Cassandra to make sure you don't run into this problem.

Ordinarily, I'd say you can workaround the problem by moving the old files out of the `data/` directories but one of the files relates to roles:

```
system_auth/roles-5bc52802de2535edaeab188eecebb090/la-1-big-Data.db
```

If you remove this file, you will lose the roles contained in it. If you have a copy of the roles somewhere else, you should be able to recreate them once the node is back online. Cheers!